# "String index out of range: 5"

Tags: java, loop, for

Está ocorrendo o erro mencionado na pergunta no meu programa em java.

O programa se trata de um leitor de código de barras. O usuário informa os dígitos do código (com exceção do último). Será feito a soma dos números q estão na posição ímpar, e os da posição ímpar. Depois existem outros cálculos (que farei mais para frente) que resultam no último dígito (aquele que não foi informado pelo usuário).

Eu reduzido para de 12 para 4 dígitos informado pelo usuário, pra ficar mais simples de se acompanhar o código. Está executando, mas ao chegar na linha 26 dá erro (primeiro for, mas creio que no segundo também):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String codigo;

        do {
            System.out.println("\n\nInforme os primeiros 4 caracteres do codigo de barras: \n");
            codigo = sc.nextLine();

            if (codigo.length() != 4) {
                System.out.println("\n\nO numero informado nao corresponde a 4 caracteres.");
            }

        } while (codigo.length() != 4); 

        int somaImpar = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= codigo.length(); i = i + 2) {
            int numConvertido = Integer.parseInt(codigo.substring(i, (i + 1)));
            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            somaImpar = somaImpar + numConvertido;

            if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println("Soma dos impares: " + somaImpar);
            }
        }

        int somaPar = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= codigo.length(); i = i + 2) {
            int numConvertido2 = Integer.parseInt(codigo.substring(i, (i + 1)));
            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            somaPar = somaPar + numConvertido2;

            if (i == 3) {
                System.out.println("Soma dos pares: " + somaPar);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Já tentei mudar a condição do for de `i < 5` para `i == 4`, colocar outros valores, mas continua dando erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é sim no seu `for` (e aconteceria nos dois).

`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 2)`

Você diz que ele deve iterar enquanto o `i` for menor que 5; manda o usuário digitar 4 números. De cara já é um problema, pois se você percorresse os dígitos um a um teria um total de 5 (posições 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4 da variável `codigo`).

Mas seu erro estoura nessa linha:

```
int numConvertido = Integer.parseInt(codigo.substring(i, (i + 1)));
```

Seu contador incrementa dois por iteração do `for` (`i = i + 2`), então pense na terceira execução, quando i = 4; o `numConvertido` receberá `codigo.substring(4, 5)`, quando na verdade o código só tem 4 dígitos.

Você precisa rever esse for nos dois pontos:

- a condição de parada deveria ser  `i < codigo.length()`
- a iteração deveria ser de apenas um (`i++`)

Comment: entendi... mas não seria melhor utilizar i <= codigo.length ? e se eu colocar o i++, então deveria colocar uma condição que só execute caso o número seja ímpar, né? pq senão ele irá somar par com ímpar...

Comment: `i <= codigo.length` não atende porque o caracter inicial da string é a posição 0, então indo de 0 até igual ao tamanho máximo, você teria uma posição a mais (gerando o erro atual)

Comment: quanto ao `i++`, acho que dá pra melhorar um pouco seu método, já que utiliza sempre um único caracter. `int numConvertido = Integer.parseInt(codigo[i]);`. Assim ele irá converter apenas o dígito correto. Com isso você pode até manter a condição de `i = i + 2` porque o erro exibido não ocorre

Comment: foi mal. Corrigindo a conversão em java: `int numConvertido = Character.getNumericValue(codigo.charAt(i));`

Comment: deu certinho! valeu, chapa. dps vou dar uma pesquisa pra entender melhor esse `Character.getNumericValue`.